# ASP.NET MVC Updating User Profile (Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, profile

I'm a beginner to ASP.NET and I am having a problem with adding "User Update" function once the user is logged in.

I've tried adding codes to controller page as below but it won't work. I'd appreciate it if anyone could give me advice how to fix these issues.

I used entity framework and below is my code

-CONTROLLER-

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        TravelExpertsEntities db = new TravelExpertsEntities();
...


 public ActionResult Edit()
        {


            string username = User.Identity.Name;

            // Fetch the userprofile
            Customer user = db.Customers.Where(u => u.CustUserId.Equals(username)).FirstOrDefault();

            // Construct the viewmodel
            Customer model = new Customer();
            model.CustFirstName = user.CustFirstName;
            model.CustLastName = user.CustLastName;
            model.CustEmail = user.CustEmail;
           //...

            return View(model);


        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Customer user)
        {
            using (TravelExpertsEntities db = new TravelExpertsEntities())
            {

                var usr = db.Customers.Where(u => u.CustUserId.Equals(user.CustUserId) && u.CustPassword.Equals(user.CustPassword)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    // Update fields
                    user.CustFirstName = usr.CustFirstName;
                    user.CustLastName = usr.CustLastName;
                    user.CustEmail = usr.CustEmail;
                    //...
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
            }

            return View(user);
        }
}

-MODEL-
public partial class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        public string CustFirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        public string CustLastName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
        public string CustAddress { get; set; }
     //...

    }
```

Comment: Have you CustPassword in plain text in database? If not then remove u.CustPassword.Equals(user.CustPassword) from where condition.

Answer (score 0):

@M.K. Kim try this :

`

```
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {


        string username = User.Identity.Name;

        // Fetch the userprofile
        Customer user = db.Customers.Where(u => u.CustUserId.Equals(username)).FirstOrDefault();


        return View(user);
    }
```

`

so you can change your controller to look like this

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Customer user)
    {
        using (TravelExpertsEntities db = new TravelExpertsEntities())
        {
            if (user!= null)

                //...
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

But it will be good coding practice to use a  ViewModel next time. this might be of help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Comment: thanks for your reply. but it's not working.. could you be a little more specific>?

Comment: made some changes to the Answer, hope it helps you solve the issue.

Comment: thank you but still not working. Should I add some codes toit?